# Wordpress elementor not showing list items correctly

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using Wordpress with a PremiumPress theme. I am trying to create a page with text, but when I write a bullet list in the text editor it doesn't show up as a bullet list on the web page:

[image]

The text version looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Test item 1</li>
<li>Test item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out what is going on. I saw something about my theme might have overwritten the styling for lists, but my theme doesn't use the style.css file. I am using elementor free so I can't use the Custom CSS option in the Advanced tab either.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Elementor widget called "Icon List". You can select bullet icons and every option can have the same bullet icon or a different one.
Here's a further guide: https://elementor.com/help/icon-list-widget/

Comment: I am creating policys, like cookie policy, where bullets are in the text, similar to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy. In the text editor in Elementor there is bullet list option and I can see them there, just not appearing in the page to the right. I appreciate the workaround, but this is not an answer to the question.